# Combining two if statements into VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy multiple sheets from one workbook to another with one action.  As of now I have to select the workbook I am copying from twice in order to copy all the data I want on to the workbook I am running the macro on.  Is there anyway to eliminate the need of two actions from the below code?  Thanks!

```
`Sub Get_Data_From_File()
Dim Filetoopen As Variant
Dim openbook As Workbook


Filetoopen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="browse for workbook", filefilter:="excel files(*.xlsx*),*xlsx*")
If Filetoopen <> False Then
Set openbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filetoopen)
openbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:K1200").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
openbook.Close False
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Filetoopen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="browse for workbook", filefilter:="excel files(*.xlsx*),*xlsx*")
If Filetoopen <> False Then
Set openbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filetoopen)
openbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:K1200").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("M10").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
openbook.Close False
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub`
```

I have not come up with a solution.  I keep getting errors for what I am trying.

Comment: Move the lines `openbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:K1200").Copy`
`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("M10").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` into the first section, right before `openbook.Close False`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing PasteSpecial xlPasteValues with directly setting cell values.
Your original logic can certainly be accomplished within a single file open as well.

```vb
Sub Get_Data_From_File()
    Dim Filetoopen As Variant
    Dim openbook As Workbook
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Filetoopen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="browse for workbook", _
        filefilter:="excel files(*.xlsx*),*xlsx*")
    If Filetoopen <> False Then
        Set oSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set openbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filetoopen)
        With openbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:K1200")
            oSht.Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
        End With
        With openbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:K1200")
            oSht.Range("M10").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
        End With
        openbook.Close False
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```